# Getting the maximum value of a query in Grafana for Prometheus

Tags: aggregation, grafana, prometheus

So I have a query in grafana using prometheus that is tabled. The issue is that Prometheus polls the data set every minute and generates a lot of data even if nothing is changing on the counter. When I try to filter my query using `max` or `max_over_time` I am still not able to only have the maximum value for a day. The idea is to only having the maximum counter value being shown for THAT day and that day only and not show every ping that Prometheus made.
My current query looks like so (below) but I have tried many variations and nothing gives. Any ideas?

```
max(random_query_by_process_status) by (lifecycle_status,aggregated_lifecycle_status,po)
```

or

```
max_over_time(random_query_by_process_status[24h])
```

or other variations and zilch

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your dashboard to automatically refresh every minute, then disable automatic refreshing from the dropdown at the top-right of your dashboard. You should also make sure that the query is an instant query (the *Instant* switch below the query textarea is on), as the instant value is likely the only value you need.